# std::remove_if() problem with the for looping

Tags: c++, std-function, remove-if

my code was

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void tes(std::string s)
{
    cout << "tes " << s << '\n';
}

void tes2(std::string s)
{
    cout << "tes " << s << '\n';
}

void tes3(std::string s)
{
    cout << "tes " << s << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    using FuncType = std::function<void(std::string&)>;
    std::list<std::pair<int, FuncType>> events =
    { 
        {1, std::bind(tes, "1")}, 
        {2, std::bind(tes2, "2")},
        {3, std::bind(tes3, "3")} };
    
    int t = 1;
    auto remove_func = [&t](std::pair<int, FuncType> pair)
        -> bool
    {
        return pair.first == t;
    };
    
    events.remove_if(remove_func);
    for (auto ev : events)
    {
        std::cout << ev.first << ' ' ;
        ev.second;
    }
    
}
```

the result just display ev.first, but not the ev.second. what happened??
how to resolve this problem?? i mean display the string in FuncType function
such "2" and "3". or fixed this code properly to work to display each.

Comment: `ev.second;` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in the posted code

```
// ...
void tes(std::string s)
{ //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
// ...
using FuncType = std::function<void(std::string&)>;
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
std::list<std::pair<int, FuncType>> events =
{ 
    {1, std::bind(tes, "1")}, 
    {2, std::bind(tes2, "2")},
    {3, std::bind(tes3, "3")}
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
};
```

The functions like `tes` have *one* parameter of type `std::string`, the alias `FuncType` is a `std::function` with *one* parameter of type `std::string&`, but the pairs in `events` are assigned the results of `std::bind`, which have *zero* parameters (they are, well, binded).

Moreover, in the printing loop

```
for (auto ev : events)
{
    std::cout << ev.first << ' ' ;
    ev.second;                       // <- This does nothing, it should be a call.
}
```

The fix<sup>1</sup> is straightforward:

```
using FuncType = std::function<void(void)>;
//                                 ^^^^^^

// ...

for (auto ev : events)
{
    std::cout << ev.first << ' ' ;
    ev.second();
    //       ^^
}
```

---

<sup>1) https://godbolt.org/z/5f8srj9va</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Fix the misprint:

```
    std::cout << ev.first << ' ' << ev.second;
```